# Issue with the python script for OAuth 2.0 token using HTTP POST?

Tags: python, api

I am trying to use an reporting API but when I use the script to get a access token I keep getting the error " No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("")

payload = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxx"

headers = { 'content-type': "application/json" }

conn.request("POST", "https://reporting.fyber.com/auth/v1/token", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

This is the information on their website.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why is the string as param in http.client.HTTPSConnection("") empty? Is that intentional?

Comment: Never post the client_secret publicly !

Comment: @AydinK. That's just the sample key. Its not mine. But Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is caused by

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("")
```

Seems the server refuses cause there is no Url(:Port) specified. Maybe add your destination as param

Try it with

```
 conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('www.python.org',(optional) portnumber)
```

Or check the firewall + port - rules of your server.

Edit:

> An HTTPConnection instance represents one transaction with an HTTP server. It should be instantiated passing it a host and optional port number. If no port number is passed, the port is extracted from the host string if it has the form host:port, else the default HTTP port (80) is used. If the optional timeout parameter is given, blocking operations (like connection attempts) will timeout after that many seconds (if it is not given, the global default timeout setting is used). The optional source_address parameter may be a tuple of a (host, port) to use as the source address the HTTP connection is made from. The optional blocksize parameter sets the buffer size in bytes for sending a file-like message body.

https://docs.python.domainunion.de/3/library/http.client.html. Even if this does not fix your error, it is recommended to instantiate the client.connection with a host and a port.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because nothing is listening to IP port.

May be try this,

`conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('www.python.org')`

or

`conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('www.python.org',80)`